# C++ Variable after function end

Tags: c++, winapi, variables, scope, wininet

I have the following code:

```
void SendRequest(HINTERNET connection, LPCWSTR method, LPCWSTR referer,LPCWSTR path,WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK whCallback){    
    HINTERNET request;
    request=WinHttpOpenRequest( connection, 0,path,0,referer,WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,0);
    WinHttpSetStatusCallback(request, (WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK)whCallback,WINHTTP_CALLBACK_FLAG_ALL_NOTIFICATIONS,0);
    REQUEST_CONTEXT cpContext;
    WinHttpSendRequest(request,WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,(DWORD_PTR)&cpContext);
};
```

WinHttpSendRequest does not block, so once it is executed, the function ends. However, WinHttpSendRequest callback to another function with the cpContext as a parameter. So my question is, doe cpContext gets destroyed after the function ends? Does this result in a a memory leak since there is no way to access cpContext outside the function? How can I do this in best C++ practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cpContext` is destroyed at the end of the function. This results in undefined behavior because `cpContext` may be destroyed before the callback is invoked. If you dereference the pointer to it from within the callback, this is undefined behavior. One way to solve this would be to avoid using a locally-scoped variable:

```
REQUEST_CONTEXT* cpContext = new REQUEST_CONTEXT();
WinHttpSendRequest(request,WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,(DWORD_PTR)cpContext);
```

Don't forget to `delete` it within the callback function.

The leak would be the `HINTERNET` handle, unless you are closing it in your callback. This handle needs to be closed with `WinHttpCloseHandle`, but you cannot close it while the asynchronous request is active.

Comment: So in order to fix both issues, I can add a global list of REQUEST_CONTEXT struct type and move the HINTERNETHANDLE to that list. One more question, because i want to understand what im doing: requestcontexes.push_front(cpContext), adds a copy of the element to the globally declared list right? not a reference to cpContext?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to use a lock to protect this list, as it may be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what `REQUEST_CONTEXT` is. If that's an object then `cpContext` gets destroyed. If it's a pointer, then just the pointer gets destroyed.

Looking at your code it's an actual object (because you're passing the address) so based from what you've given us, I'd say it gets destroyed when `SendRequest()` ends, and there's no memory leak.

Shouldn't be hard to test, right?

Comment: REQUEST_CONTEXT is a struct, which contains a buffer for incoming data. So maybe I need to declare it globaly. Because when there is data available from the http request (initiated by sendrequest), it will notify via a callback

Answer (score 0):

Like all local variables, `cpContext` indeed goes out of scope. That's not a memory leak, but worse. That callback will be using an object after its lifetime ended.

If you know 100% certainly that the callback will be called precisely once, you can allocate `cpContext` with `new REQUEST_CONTEXT`, and delete it from the callback. If you don't know, the problem is much worse. You'll have to use API-specific methods to figure out how long the object should stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

cpContext is allocated in the stack as any other local variable of your SendRequest() function.

Your current solution is worse that a memory leak. It is not that you are leaking memory. The fact is that the object no longer exist but you still hold a pointer to that address.

From my point of view, this is undefined behaviour. Don't do this.

You have the following options to solve your problem:

1. Use a global variable for your cpContext variable.
2. Allocate your cpContext on the heap via new.
3. Allocate cpContext in another context that you are sure will live until the callback finishes.